# What is fast way to add 300 sheets with data to Excel?

Tags: excel, rpa, uipath

Currently I’m using Excel Application Scope which is unchecked AutoSave and unchecked Visible, and using Save Workbook as the first picture below.

- Estimated execution time is 10 minutes.
- Adding new sheet is slower as the sheets increase.

[image: Add 300 sheets to Excel (1)]

[image: Add 300 sheets to Excel (2)]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Write Range` activity instead. This will be **4-times** faster.

[image: Add 300 sheets to Excel (3)]
[image: Add 300 sheets to Excel (4)]